# Proving Two Taylor Polynomials Are Equal

Tags: calculus

> I am trying to prove the Following:
>   Let there two polynomials: $p(x),q(x)$ at a degree on $n$ at most, and $$f(x)=p(x)+o(x-x_0)^n=q(x)+o(x-x_0)^n$$ therefore $p(x)=q(x)$

I have come to the following limit:

$$\lim_{ x \to x_0} \frac{\sum_{k=0}^n (a_k(x-x_0)^k-b_k(x-x_0)^k}{(x-x_0)^n}$$

Now it said that there are a condition on $0\leq k\leq n-1$ so that there will be a limit, and one more condition so it will be $0$.

What should be the conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment, assume $x_0 = 0$.
Since $0 = f(x)-f(x) = p(x)-q(x) + o(x^n)$ we find $p(x) - q(x) = o(x^n)$. The left hand side is a polynomial of degree at most $n$, say $q(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i$. Then divide both sides by $x^n$ to get
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^{i-n} = o(1)
$$
Unless $i=n$, then $x^{i-n} \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$, so we must have $c_i = 0$ for all $i \neq n$. Thus the previous line reduces to
$$
c_0 = o(1)
$$ 
from which it follows that $c_0 = 0$ as well.
Thus $q(x) = 0$, so $p(x) = q(x)$.
Now note that by shifting coordinates, we can remove the assumption $x_0 = 0$.

Comment: few questions:
1. Why if $f(x)-f(x) = p(x)-q(x) + o(x^n)$ so $p(x) - q(x) = o(x^n)$ ?

Comment: $f(x)-f(x) = 0$, so the equation reads $p(x) - q(x) + o(x^n) = 0$, also $-o(x^n) = o(-x^n) = o(x^n)$ since multiplicative constants don't affect limits being zero ($g(x) = o(f(g))$ as $x \to 0$ means $g(x)/f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$)